# Class or Interface excepted

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Here is the code:

```
public class Tuna {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("I am a tuna fish"); // Here it says class or interface excepted
    }
}
```

I have a Tuna class above that has a eat method. In that eat method, it says class or interface expected at the print line. Even though it is running smoothly, when I hover over the print line in the `eat` method it says class or interface expected. I already checked other questions related to it but I couldn't solve it. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Image of the code]

Comment: If it can run you don't have any errors. Restart the IDE, it should make the error disappear.

Comment: @Guy I restarted the IDE, but it still shows the same error.

Comment: If just restarting does not help, you can also try File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart. This usually fixes these kinds of problems.

Comment: @Leon Thank you so much! It did made the error disappear.